# How do i add the preload html tag in images, scripts to reduce the LCP time in Pagespeed Insights

Tags: html, image-preloader, deferred-loading, preloadjs

I've been getting this error that "This is the largest contentful element painted within the viewport" and takes about 21 seconds to load. I've tried resolving this with **fetchpriority=high** but it doesn't seem to work.

Should i use this instead to load scripts, images, CSS as and when needed?

```
  <title>JS and CSS preload example</title>

  <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" />
  <link rel="preload" href="main.js" as="script" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>bouncing balls</h1>
  <canvas></canvas>

  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

and similar structure for images?

I've tried resolving this with **fetchpriority=high** but it doesn't seem to work. Browser is still rendering the complete page and is not prioritizing the LCP element.